# 1,195,017,281 Nodes loaded for US Dataset (Load OSM File Tool), building indexes for 2 weeks, Is this normal

Tags: openstreetmap, network-dataset, geofabrik

Downloaded the OSM file from Geofabrik for the United States

I have the Nodes loaded, but the "Building Point indexes" has been going on for two weeks, and there is no real way to see if it is still functioning correctly that I can tell. It has not stalled or become unresponsive and still looks like the HD is reading. I don't want to quit after all this time, but my patience is wearing thin, and so is my boss's. My end goal is to create a network dataset. Is this "normal" for it to take this much time?

This is using the OSM Editor Plugin for ArcGIS 10.8.1, to a File Geodatabase on an SSD Drive.

Basically trying to follow this workflow, I need it to do routing in ArcGIS Environment. https://gascuk.github.io/OpenStreetMap-ArcGIS/workflows/extended/

Comment: Which software? Under what configuration? Hopefully a database is involved here...

Comment: Sorry, added more detail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It has completed after about 30+ days of processing.